# How do I set the first entry of a combo box to empty? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

My code is retrieving player names from a database and outputting them into a combo box. However I want the first entry of the combo box to be empty, how can I achieve this?

If it helps, here is my code. Please note I only have 1 option box code in HTML as I'm editing phpBB. The <-- BEGIN clubplayer --> is a loop.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is really more of an HTML question, and that tag should be added for future findability. I'd add it myself, but do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
<select name="id" id="id">
```

Add

```
<option></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a empty

```
<options value=""></option>
```

Before `<!-- BEGIN.....`

Answer (score 1):

Set the first option in your select like this:

```
<option value="">--select--</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the same solution as others, but there's always a different solution available...
Before your **while** loop, you can:

```
$template->assign_block_vars('clubplayer', array(
    'PLAYERS' => '' #assign empty value
));
```